# Using a long random alphanumeric string to serve data

Tags: database, security, email, url, random

My web app receives an email address and some user information via an external source, validates that information, then should send an email out with a link to that user. The link has a small amount of value, so it should be secure.

Would it be enough to use a 64 character string of length 200 to protect against any attacks on the website?

**Pseudocode:**

```
id = '';
length = 200;
characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-'; 
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    id += characters[random(characters.length)];
}        
link = WEB_URL + "?" + id;
// create this url with valuable information on the server
// email link with id appended in URL fragment to user
```

For conflict resolution, I plan on using `sha512` to store the hash of the URL into a database with an email address for lookup. I am assuming using a salt would be overkill. It wouldn't be very easy to brute force the id anyway.

Is there any security issue I could encounter using this method? I want to avoid users being bothered with log in screens or cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring the email getting intercepted, I think you're doing about everything (practically) that you can do to prevent an attack.  But, the weak link is the possibility of the email getting intercepted.  Making sure that your mail server connects to the recipient's mail server by way of TLS (transport layer security), if the recipient's mail server supports TLS, will help - otherwise the message is sent unencrypted.  If you're sending these through a remote mail server, then you might also want to make sure your app connects to that mail server through SSL or TLS as well, for the same reason.

Comment: The backbone hop is where governments tap data - not hackers.

Comment: All the more reason to use TLS to connect to he remote MTA.